# How to use "amnesty" in a sentence?

Tags: american-english

My own example:

1. > Lord chancellor may put an amnesty on you if you quit retaliating against the government.
2. > There is no way the national law amnesty a person rebeling agains the government.

Answer (score 2):

give/grant amnesty works fine.

> 1. Lord chancellor may grant you an amnesty if you quit retaliating against the government.

as a noun:

> 2. There is no way the national law will (give/grant) amnesty to a person rebelling against the government.

as a verb :

> 2. There is no way the national law amnesties(will amnesty) a person rebelling against the government.

for more reference : http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/amnesty